# Relational table SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle

```
(1) Create a relational table TOTAPPS(anum,totap) that contains information 
about the numbers of applicants (anum) and the total number 
of applications (totap) submitted by each applicant. If an applicant submitted 
no application then a value ofattribute   
totap should be equal to zero. Load data to a relational table TOTAPPS.
```

So i just want to understand that the relational table isn't using following query

```
CREATE TABLE test_table ( anum INTEGER, totap INTEGER );
```

and how do i point the anum to count the number of applicants using the relational table

example my applicants table like this:

```
//Applicant
A# 
---------
1 
2 
3
4
5

//Application
A#         POSITION
--------------------
1            CEO
1            GM
2            DIRECTOR
3            MANAGER
```

so when i SELECT * FROM TOTAPPS, the following result should be like this:

```
//TOTAPPS
ANUM          TOTAP
-------------------
  1             2
  2             1
  3             1
  4             0 
  5             0
```

i must insert manually or when i create the relational table i can straight count it?

Comment: Presumably you have a table containing applications, as well as one containing applicants - where each applicant can have many applications? The requirement doesn't make sense though; if `anum` is the number of applicants then that's a single value, the count of records in the applicants table. `totap` could be the count of records in the applications table; but then "submitted by each applicant" doesn't fit. So it maybe really just wants a left outer join between the two tables, and an aggregate count of applications for each applicant?

Comment: then? what should i do ? to create a new relational table