# SELECT clause then update the data

Tags: sql, oracle

Table : Employee AND Application

```
//Employee
NAME            SALARY
-----------------------
CHIRS           40000
JOHN            30000
MARY            20000

//Application
NAME          P#
-----------------
CHIRS        0001
JOHN         0002
```

As the table above, we can see that only MARY don't have any application, so salary of MARY will be increase 10%

Following query:

```
UPDATE FROM EMPLOYEE E SET E.SALARY = E.SALARY*1.10
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM APPLICATION);
```

isn't my following query correct or wrong? thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE FROM EMPLOYEE E
    SET E.SALARY = E.SALARY*1.10
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM APPLICATION A WHERE A.NAME = E.NAME);
```

Without the correlation, the subquery would always return 2 rows.  Clearly, these exist, so the `where` clause always fails.

Comment: just for own understanding, why select 1 only? if i have multiple data. will it works also?

Comment: @user3553846 . . . The `not exists` clause only cares if rows are returned by the subquery.  `1` is both efficient and requires very little typing.  Anything can go there, but I don't like the use of `NULL` (which you can sometimes see in this case).  As for multiple conditions, you would put those in the `where` clause.

Comment: can you help me check this thread and help ? thanks you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23674644/relational-table-sql-plus?noredirect=1#comment36374613_23674644

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE FROM EMPLOYEE E
SET E.SALARY = E.SALARY*1.10
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(A.Name) FROM APPLICATION A WHERE A.NAME = E.NAME) = 0;
```

The performance of your query could improve if you try to use a "Count" clause